# If/Else statement (Mute Button Unity 3D)

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a mute button in my game in Unity, but I'm running into a few problems.   I need to create a if/else statement, to show when the button is press mute the audio and display this image, and vice versa.

I am guessing I should put my if/else statement into my onClicked method, but not for sure where to start from there.

My Code:

```
override public void OnClicked()
{
   print ("OnClicked : " + gameObject.name);            
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to create"? Don't you use Unity gui button?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a button to the canvas - the GameObject that contains all the GUI - (to the scene).
2. Attach a script that has a public OnClick event handler to the canvas.
3. Now select the button and attach the OnClick event handler to its click property.
4. In the script you can add a property `bool IsSoundON = true;` to be changed inside the OnClick and then apply your code for ON/OFF the sound.

Comment: I have added my code into the question. I don't understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

to mute the sound, you could add:

```
  AudioListener.volume = 0f;
```

source: [Unity scripting API referring to audio listener](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener-volume.html)